# How to remove 'bouncing effect' when scrolling GridView (winrt, xaml)?

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a page with GridView that contains 5 large rectangles:

```
 <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
     <GridView Padding="120,90,46,40">
        <GridView.Items>
           <Rectangle Width="450" Height="300" Fill="Green" Opacity="0.7" />
           <Rectangle Width="450" Height="300" Fill="Blue" Opacity="0.7" />
           <Rectangle Width="450" Height="300" Fill="Orange" Opacity="0.7" />
           <Rectangle Width="450" Height="300" Fill="Green" Opacity="0.7" />
           <Rectangle Width="450" Height="300" Fill="Red" Opacity="0.7" />
     </GridView.Items>
     </GridView>
 </Grid>
```

When scrolling the GridView to the left and the left rectangle is 'touching' the left side of the tablet screen then all tiles 'bounce' back and forth several times.

Is there any way how to disable this 'bounce' effect? What I have seen is that this 'bouncing' is related to the number of tiles and the width of the screen (in my case it is 1366). When I have more then 6 tiles, the effect is not visible.

Comment: any luck figuring this out?

Comment: This problem 'disappeared´ after we upgraded to Win 8.1 and target platform of the app was changed to 8.1. So it seems that this was a problem of Win 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

The GridView and ScrollViewer have this bouncing effect to show a user he has reached the end of a list. if you don't have this effect it can feel for a user that scrolling is not responding. There is no way to change this.

When you have more then 6 tiles (and you actually have to scroll) this effect will be visible if you scroll to 1 side and then try to continue scrolling.

What do you mean with "back and forth" several times? this shouldn't happen it should only bounce back once. i've copied your code in an empty project and it does not bounce back and forth but only once. (do you have other code that could influence scrolling?)

Comment: When running the app on a tablet, try to swipe to the left. The screen moves to the left. When the left rectangle reaches the edge of the screen it bounces back. Then the right rectangle reaches the right end of the screen and bounces back. This is repeated several times (back and forth). I could see this also when running the app on the simulator.

Comment: on what resolution do you test this? i added your grid to an empty solution and it only bounces 1x. it doesnt bounce from the right anymore

Comment: The resolution of the tablet display is 1366 x 768. When app is started then the right rectangle is slightly over the right edge of the screen. When I have more rectangles then this effect is not visible.